# How to sort attribute keys when combining into an array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject

I just learned how to retrieve the attribute keys from a CoreData database and to put them into an array.  It's working fine except every time the method runs, it generates the dataset in a different order every time.  I just have 3 keys right now - name, sex, type.

Is there something I can do to make it iterate through the keys in the same order each time? I'm going to make more properties and using the information to populate a tableview, so I'd like it to be consistent.

```
["type", "sex", "name"]
["Goat", "F", "Bob"]

["sex", "name", "type"]    
["M", "Jack", "Goat"]

["name", "sex", "type"]
["Bob", "F", "Goat"]

["type", "name", "sex"]
["Goat", "Jack", "M"]

["name", "sex", "type"]
["Bob", "F", "Goat"]






func generateAttributeList(_ animal:Animal) -> Array<String> {

    let dictAttributes = animal.entity.attributesByName
    var arrAttributeTitles:Array<String> = []
        
    for (key, _) in dictAttributes {
        arrAttributeTitles.append(key)
    }
    return arrAttributeTitles
}


//makes the Value Array 
func generateValueList () {
    for (name, _) in animal!.entity.attributesByName {
  
        let animalValue = animal!.value(forKey: name) as! String
        childValues.append(animalValue)

    }
    //var attributesByName: [String : NSAttributeDescription] { get }
    
}
```

Comment: Just sort the array before you return it

Comment: Why do you care about _order_? The important thing is that the key is paired with its value, and in every case you showed, it is.

Comment: yes, it does keep them in the correct dictionary order which is critical. but I'd like to display them in some logical or intuitive order in the tableview.  I can't just sort the array alphabetically because then the dictionary pairs won't be correct.

Comment: No, I don't get it. As long as you can retrieve, say, the name for each one, what do you care how it is ordered among the other keys? The table view knows where to put the name.

Comment: Sorry, I'm close to brand new and just stumbling along as I learn.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some really experienced folks in the comments questioning why you would need to do this and pointing out there may be a better approach. But if you decide you really need to do this, this is how you can.

Return the keys sorted, you don't really need to copy them, so your first function would look like this.

```swift
func generateAttributeList(_ animal:Animal) -> [String] {

    let dictAttributes = animal.entity.attributesByName
    return dictAttributes.keys.sorted()
}
```

Then pass the keys into the function that returns the values to produce the values in order.

```swift
func generateValueList (order: [String]) -> [String] {
    var childValues = [String]()
    for key in order { 
        let animalValue = animal!.value(forKey: key) as! String
        childValues.append(animalValue)
    }
    return childValues
}
```

Or more succinctly

```swift
func generateValueList (order: [String]) -> [String] {
    return order.map { animal!.value(forKey: $0) as! String }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!!  I really appreciate your help.  It's really wonderful how people help each other on this site.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved you problem.

Comment: Can you tell me just very summarily what the $0 does?  I think I otherwise understand the logic of how that is working.  the 2nd function is receiving the ordered list of attribute names and using that list as a map to create the values.  Genius!

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html Here is very good guide, it will tell you about the $0 notation and other good stuff.